# app not working on emulator

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android app development.I am trying to make an app that accesses the contacts from the phone.My console shows succesful installation of the app but it doesn't get started in the emulator.Could anyone please tell me what could be the possible reasons??

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity    { 
ListView lvItem;
private Button btnAdd;
String displayName="", emailAddress="", phoneNumber="";
ArrayList<String> contactlist=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView_items);  
   btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
   itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contactlist);
   lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
   btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           readContacts();
       }
   });
}

private void readContacts()
{
    ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        displayName="";emailAddress=""; phoneNumber="";
        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));       
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI,null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
        while (emails.moveToNext()) 
        { 
            emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
            break;
        }
        emails.close();
        if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
        {
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) 
            {
                 phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                break;
            }
            pCur.close();
        }
            contactlist.add("DisplayName: "+displayName+", PhoneNumber: "+phoneNumber+", EmailAddress: "+ emailAddress+"\n");
            itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    cursor.close(); 
}
```

}

manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.contacts"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >
        <uses-sdk
           android:minSdkVersion="8"
           android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
               android:name="com.example.contacts.MainActivity"
               android:label="@string/app_name" >
               <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: We are not psychic! Without any code we cannot help. Sorry.

Comment: Please open logcat and give us a some details.

Answer (score 1):

Try it on an actual phone, the emulator does not have any contacts on it

Comment: I agree with @user1838169 try it on a phone and then see.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason is that you have not added this code in the activity in your menifest file

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

so the your application is being installed successfully but it is not launching due to above code.plz add the above code and it will work...

Comment: there is no crash.On the console its showing starting app on emulator but nothing is displayed on the emulator.

Comment: Thank You Its working.There was some problem with my emulator

Answer (score 0):

Check your Manifest File carefully Activity name and permission for accessing contacts.